# Exponential numbers to be converted to string

Tags: c#, excel, .net-4.0, exponential

I have an issue. I'm importing data from an excel file, data like codes and stuff.
for importing I'm using [LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel)
The problem is that one of the excel's columns contains codes like "A2C235425345345" or "12441523543454454". This data of this column is not formated as string or numbers. So, when read from the excel file, instead of that value "6.57621e+009".
So now i need a way to convert that value back to the initial one, using C# and .NET framework 4.0

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: What is that string value meant to be? Are you sure it's meant to be a number of some kind?

Comment: what is the value you expect to see instead of "6.57621e+009" ? and what is your code reading when excel value is "A2C235425345345" ?

Comment: My first instinct was the `A2C235425345345` code was hex, but of course the number would be massively huge.  Perhaps it's a formula.

Comment: Thank for your interest! The string in the Excel are product codes - not Hexa or anything else. Just a string that may contain the prefix "A2C". Instead of the exponential value i would like to see the code itsefl, as found in the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Use an apostrophe `'` before the string value and then pass it to Excel.

I am assuming you are exporting the data to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a mapping block for the convert columns.

```
public static List<ExcelReqests> LoadRequest( string path)
{
     var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(path);
     excel.AddMapping<ExcelRequests>(x => x.COLUMNNAME, "COLUMNNAME",
                s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
                    ? decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimal dummy)
                        ?
                        dummy.ToString("#0")
                        : s
                    : s);  
    return (from e in excel.Worksheet<ExcelRequests>(0)
                select e).ToList();
 }
```

PS: Attention the culture dependency in the decimal conversion process.

Comment: Add a bit more information, how does it integrate with LinqToExcel? BTW: Is it possible to format the code so that no horizontal is needed? Maybe also the text could be checked for typos, thanks in advance...